# Explicit Cast Syntax

Tags: c#, casting, explicit-conversion

What is the difference between the two lines of code below? Functionally, I believe them to be identical, but is there a certain case or best practice that would dictate which one I should use?

```
TreeViewItem selectedItem = MyTreeView.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;

TreeViewItem selectedItem = (TreeViewItem)MyTreeView.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: They're not functionally equivalent; see linked question

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is a good example of knowing how to ask the question it seems - I was looking for explicit casts, not for the `as` keyword.